Echarts prevent zooming on scroll and weird scroll behaviour
I am using echarts-for-react and I would like to prevent zoom on scroll.
Currently, I am using the following dataZoom configuration::
  dataZoom: [
     {
        type: 'inside',
        moveOnMouseMove: false,
     },
  ]

However, this creates odd scrolling behavior. It doesn't consistently prevent zooming while scrolling. Sometimes it works as expected, but other times it doesn't.
I might be approaching this issue incorrectly, but I haven’t been able to find a proper solution.
Here’s https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/t6lt55  to demonstrate the issue. Try scrolling down on the chart. You’ll notice the strange behavior I’m referring to.

Can you elaborate in detail on the strange scrolling behaviour? Only thing I notice is that scolling down the page is not working while on the chart since scrolling enables the dataZoom. If you dont want that, why use dataZoom: { type: 'inside' } ?

@MatthiasMertens
Without type: 'inside', the chart doesn’t zoom at all. I want the zoom functionality to work with the x-axis arrows, not the y-axis. This is because I need to scroll through the page using the y-axis arrow without being restricted by the chart’s zooming feature.

You could only use the slider for zooming. What do you expect to happen when scrolling the mouse wheel? Should the x-axis of the chart zoom, should the page scroll down or both at the same time?

@MatthiasMertens on x-axis it should zoom, on y-axis it should scroll the page
